# Windows phone randomly reboots

Tags: 7.8

I have a Windows phone 7 powered LG Optimus 7 which randomly reboots, and this occurs especially when it is plugged into the wall charger and receives a sms. The phone then reboots, and there is no new message on the phone - the sms just sent to me is lost after the reboot. Anyone knows what is going on here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you recently made any updates to the firmware?

Comment: I've updated from windows phone 7.5 to 7.8, haven't downloaded any new apps in the meantime.

Comment: And this started happening after the update to 7.8?

Comment: The lost sms started after the update to 7.8, but my phone has had random reboots even when running 7.5.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to Zune to see if there are any other updates available?

Comment: Yup I've tried connecting to Zune and it seems the phone is up to date. I was actually hoping the 7.8 update would fix the random reboots, but it made things worse.

Comment: What's the memory usage like? And did you try and unlock the phone?

Comment: Looks like this isn't an isolated incident: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wptips/my-lg-optimus-7-reboots-by-itself-almost-everyday/f0f3b252-5f61-4ada-ba28-c23728c16a63

Comment: I haven't tried unlocking the phone, and have never tried anything funny with it. I've also never modified the functions of Zune. Thanks for the link!

Comment: You should probably go to your network operator and ask for a replacement

Answer (score 1):

> If your device is rebooting in [a] loop [...] and it happens even after you reset your device to factory defaults, I would say [that] is a valid reason to claim warranty repair/replace[ment].
>
> Source: [Martin V., WP7 Support](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wptips/my-lg-optimus-7-reboots-by-itself-almost-everyday/f0f3b252-5f61-4ada-ba28-c23728c16a63)